# some operations on files

Tags: objective-c

I wrote this program but couldn't get the output, every time when I run this program I get the only 1st `NSlog` statement. I have created I file at this path and contents also.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool
    {
        NSString *fName = @"/Users/sahil/Documents/newfile/commands";
        NSFileManager * fm;
        NSDictionary *attr;
        fm=[NSFileManager defaultManager];

        if ([fm fileExistsAtPath: fName]== NO)
        {
            NSLog(@"file not exist");
            return 1;
        }
        if ([fm copyItemAtPath:fName toPath:@"newfile1" error:NULL] == NULL)
        {
            NSLog(@"file copy failed");
            return 2;
        }
        if ([fm contentsEqualAtPath:fName andPath:@"newfile1"]==NO)
        {
            NSLog(@"files are not =");
            return 3;
        }
        if ([fm moveItemAtPath:@"newfile1" toPath:@"newfile2" error:NULL]== NULL)
        {
            NSLog(@"file rename fail");
            return 4;
        }
        if ((attr=[fm attributesOfItemAtPath:@"newfile2" error:NULL])==nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"couldnt get file attributes");
            return 5;
        }
        NSLog(@"file size is %llu bytes",[[attr objectForKey:NSFileSize] unsignedLongLongValue]);
        if ([fm removeItemAtPath:fName error:NULL] == NULL)
        {
            NSLog(@"file removal failed");
            return 6;
        }
        NSLog(@"all ops were successful");
        NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"newfile2" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me out this problem.
Thanks

Comment: iOS or OSX, the file systems have different rules about case sensitivity. Instead to passing `NULL` as the error parameter pass a pointer to a `NSError` valuable and on failure `NSLog` the error, it will provide a reason for the failure.

Comment: Its not showing any failure instead only 1st NSlog statement came out as output

Comment: Yes, see my answer. In general it is a bad idea to ignore results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP code:

```
if ([fm fileExistsAtPath: fName]== NO)
{
    NSLog(@"file not exist");
    return 1;
}
```

will return if the `NSLog` prints so there will be no further execution in the program.

Remove the `return 1;` statement.

This assumes that "I get the only 1st NSlog statement." means the statement: `NSLog(@"file not exist");` executes.

OP code:

```
if ([fm copyItemAtPath:fName toPath:@"newfile1" error:NULL] == NULL)
{
    NSLog(@"file copy failed");
    return 2;
}
```

Adding error logging:

```
NSError *error;
if ([fm copyItemAtPath:fName toPath:@"newfile1" error:&error] == NULL)
{
    NSLog(@"file copy failed, error: %@", error);
    return 2;
}
```

Comment: Sir, now 2nd NSLog statement is executing, when I remove 2nd return statement; I have files at the given path than why not its performing coping, moving and other operations

Comment: better put if-else so you can understand what is going on and NSlog the errors

Comment: Three things: 1) Instead to passing NULL as the error parameter pass a pointer to a NSError valuable and on failure NSLog the error, it will provide a reason for the failure. 2) `@"newfile1"` does not look like a valid file path. 3) On failure returning is probably the best action.

Comment: @OMer Obaid Thanks for ur comment.I will try your idea also

Comment: @OMer I see nothing wrong with the `if` structure, on failure return. Adding `else` structure will make the code more complicated.

Comment: @Zaph sir can u please tell me how to change NULL to a pointer to a NSError value.

Comment: I tried it like this- NSError *king; and then at place of NULL I mention king. Now program is showing error

Comment: Let me try once more sir

Comment: @Zaph comment was for sahil51 sorry

Comment: @sahil51saini I updated my answer with an example of how to use `NSError`. Basically i there is an error as indicated by the return value them there will be an `NSError`.  Omer I understood.

Comment: @zaph Thanks sir, I tried in both ways and get the desired output. Thank you very much hope you will guide me in future also, thanks again thanks a lot

Comment: @OMer Obaid I tried yours also and get the desired output. Thanks for your support as well thank you very much. hope u will assist me in future also. Thanks again